# Examples of solving the geodesic equation

Tags: metric-tensor, geodesics

The geodesic equation is

$$
\frac{d^2\gamma^\lambda}{dt^2} + \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}\frac{d\gamma^\mu}{dt}\frac{d\gamma^\nu}{dt}
$$

What are some solutions to this equation that can be quickly and analytically calculated? Quickly = something can be derived and discussed in a 1h15m undergraduate lecture or less.

The simplest and rather trivial solutions are great circles on spheres, or straight lines in polar coordinates. Another rather straightforward solution is [one on Newtonian gravity.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257322/how-do-you-actually-use-the-geodesic-equation) But I am hoping to see something which is more non-trivial.

Comment: I think the motion of a particle in a FRLW spacetime should be solvable, but I also think this question will probably get closed since it asks for a list of answers.